# Move text relative to window resize, keeping it inside background image

Tags: css

I am assuming this question has been answered many times over, but unfortunately after couple hours of searching I am still not able to solve it.

Can someone tell the best way to keep text position in relation to a sibling div/image on window resize?

Please find fiddle attached:

```css
.wrapper img  {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 0;
}

.text-box {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text-box">
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/770x690"></a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ye5q4o2L/4/

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check my answer below..I have adjusted html layout and styles in proper way. try it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this, it may help with what you're trying to achieve.

**It does not set the position based on it's sibling**, rather it is relative to the parent whose size is being determined by the children.

```css
html,
body,
.wrapper {
  /* stopping overflow - just for example */
  height:100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper .img-wrapper  {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 0;
}

.wrapper img {
  z-index:1;
  
  /* stopping overflow - just for example */
  max-height:100%;
  width:auto;
  max-width:100%;
}

.text-box {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.img-wrapper a {
 /* Set to block to capture the whole img element */
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <div class="text-box">
      <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <a href="https://placeholder.com">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/770x690">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ye5q4o2L/10/

Comment: Thanks Rylee, that still not quite what I was hoping for, but thanks for the answer. I just added an additional media query, until I figure this one out.

Answer (score 2):

Since the image has a known width/height you can use them to define the width/height of the text container and then it will be easy to achieve:

```css
.wrapper img,
.text-box{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 0;
}

.text-box {
  width:770px;
  height:690px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text-box">
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/770x690"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution without specify width, height.

JSfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/hardyrajput/knzL4bqu/3/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text-box">
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/770x690"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper .text-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.wrapper a {
    display: block;
}
.wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of the sibling in advance, you can do this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* For padding */
}

.wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 0;
}

.text-box {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 770px;
  height: 690px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text-box">
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/770x690"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .wrapper {
      text-align:center;
    }
    
    .bg {
      position: relative;
      display:inline-block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .bg img  {
      width:100%;
    }
    
    .text-box {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 20px;
      left: 20px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="bg">
        <div class="text-box">
          <p>lorem ipsum</p>
          <p>lorem ipsum</p>
       </div>
        <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/770x690"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/ye5q4o2L/33/

Try this. This works fine...
Let me know if you have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```css
.wrapper{
  text-align: center;
}
.imgWrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.text-box {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="imgWrapper">
    <div class="text-box">
      <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/770x690"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The display of `.imgWrapper` is `inline-block` so it will take the size of the image, and the text-box position is `absolute` so it will be relative to its parent `.imgwrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

See this one. Here i added width:100%; in .wrapper img class.

If you need to set height. Then you can set height:100%;(Optional).

https://jsfiddle.net/xczrptw8/

```
.wrapper img  {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
width:100%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index: 0;
}

.text-box {
 z-index: 1;
 position: relative;
top: 20px;
left: 20px;
}
```